# Substitute solution into ODE to verify it holds

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

I am struggling a lot to understand how to do the very basic exercise of substituting a solution into an ODE so see whether the solution is indeed valid. Consider the following ODE:

```
ode = -pi[x] * pi'[x] - (xi + rn) * pi'[x] - delta * pi[x] + k * x;
```

My solution is as follows:

```
a0 = -(((-delta - Sqrt[4 * k + delta^2]) (rn + xi)) / (2 * (delta + 1/2 (-delta - Sqrt[4 * k + delta^2]))));
a1 = 1/2 * (-delta - Sqrt[4 * k + delta^2]);
piSol[x_] := a0 + a1 * x;
```

I can verify that the solution is correct by manual substitution:

```
FullSimplify[-(a0 + a1 * x) * (a1) - (xi + rn) * (a1) - delta * (a0 + a1 * x) + k*x] === 0
```

> True

Why does this not work?

```
FullSimplify[ode /. {pi[x] -> piSol[x], pi'[x] -> D[piSol[x], x]}] === 0
```

> False

What is the correct way to substitute a solution into an ODE to verify that it holds?

Comment: see Mathematica documentation page [CheckTheResultsOfDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CheckTheResultsOfDSolve.html)

Comment: I get True for the last check. Maybe try restarting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Function`:

```
FullSimplify[ode /. pi -> Function[x, piSol[x]]] === 0

(*True*)
```